# Login to Titanium Studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-studio

A little over a year ago, I shelved several projects and went on to do other work. Now I'm finding that I cannot login to my installation of Titanium Studio. I clicked the 'troubleshooting login' link and it pointed me to the Appcelerator page for "Errors Logging In to Studio". There it suggested that I try the following command:

curl -F "username=XXXX" -F "password=YYYY" https://dashboard.appcelerator.com/api/v1/auth/login

When I did so, with my email address (which contains a '-'), it returned: 
"Username must be a valid email address." Of course it is a valid email address, and Titanium confirmed it years ago. It is also the same email address I used to access the Appcelerator website.

I changed my email address to one that doesn't include the '-'. Same result.

Has Appcelerator completely locked us out of Titanium Studio?

Any suggestions regarding how to get past this hurdle would be greatly appreciated!! (When I last used Appcelerator Studio, it didn't feel comfortable, so I went back to Titanium. I'm really hoping that I don't have to start over on my apps.)

Thank you in advance!
Rob

Comment: It looks like they are 'un-open sourcing' Titanium (blocking access to Titanium Studio, etc.). As I only do mobile development as a hobby currently, I'm looking at other avenues. Meteor.js looks the most promising because it leverages Javascript, Node.js and looks to be very well supported by their community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appcelerator discontinued Titanium studio and replaced with Appcelerator Studio with the integrated enterprise features - Arrow, performance and test services, etc for easy development of mobile applications.

You can't use titanium studio login credentials with Appcelerator Studio. However, you can get a free trial access  http://www.appcelerator.com/signup/ and get started with Appcelerator Studio.

You can import all your old projects to Appcelerator studio and I don't think you need to put extra effort to start working on this.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium studio was discontinued a while ago, easily over a year now. You do need to use appcelerator studio or your favorite editor if you don't like studio. You can compile and run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Also verify your account on their website. It seems they have recently changed some things. Eg. my "forever trial" (which should have been a perpetual Indie, but that's another discussion) seems to be expired recently. So maybe you have to take some additional administrative steps in order to be able to continue working with your apps.